# How to manage mysql database table index

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, optimization

I am not aware of how to manage an mysql database table index and I attempted to implement it, but I am uncertain about managing the index for this extensive MySQL database table (Will do it at my end but just need some information to do with this table).

I am using different queries and use this fields as needed for search: `id`, `post_id`, `imdbRating`, `genres`, `year`, `cast`, and `posterURLs`.

Slower queries to get clear ideas that why i want to use indexing.

```
/* QUERY 1 using for search filters, filter with tr.tax_id, pd.type or mo.streamingInfo  (slower) */
SELECT pd.id, pd.title, pd.slug, mo.posterURLs, mo.imdbRating
FROM posts pd
INNER JOIN movies mo ON (pd.id = mo.post_id) 
INNER JOIN term_relation tr ON (pd.id = tr.obj_id) /* Used with filter (skippable) */
WHERE pd.type = 'movies' /* Used with filters (skippable) */
  AND pd.status = 1
  AND mo.type = "movie"
  AND mo.streamingInfo REGEXP "jio|zee5|voot" /* Used with filters (skippable) */
  AND tr.tax_id IN (123456,78910,111213) /* Used with filter (skippable) */
GROUP BY pd.id
ORDER BY mo.year DESC, pd.date DESC /* Can be mo.year DESC or mo.imdbRating ASC/DESC  */
LIMIT 0, 24;
```

```
/* QUERY 2 only from movie table (slower) */
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE post_id='123456'; /* Resolved with INDEX(post_id) */
SELECT post_id FROM movies WHERE cast REGEXP "(Cast Title)" AND post_id <> 123456 AND post_id <> 0 ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 12
```

I already have a composite index on the `posts` table, which using these index `idx_type_status_date: (type, status, date, id)` with their respective orders. However, I'm wondering if it's also possible to create a separate index on the movies table?

Comment: Are these "words" or "substrings"?  "jio|zee5|voot"  It matters for picking between `REGEXP` and `FULLTEXT`.

Comment: These are substrings,```streamingInfo```, ```cast``` storing long JSON format data.

Comment: If performance is the goal, you may need to move things out of JSON into extra tables and have 1-to-many relationships.

Comment: Yes, I will think about moving ```cast``` and ```streamingInfo``` columns into extra tables.

Comment: _And_ have one row in the new `cast` table for each cast member.  (This gets rid of the JSON and will have many more rows.)

Comment: Yes, That's great idea and will think about remove use of JSON string with ```cast```.

Comment: And maybe do the same for `streamingInfo`?  Is it just "genres"?  See also the `SET` datatype.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking to create relationships but having 30k+ rows so, given ```FULLTEXT(cast)``` is already working now, but about ```streamingInfo``` create new column called ```streamingType:varchar(255)``` which stores only ```jio,zee5,voot,etc``` and ```INDEX(streamingType)``` so, I think it works for now, what do you think?

Comment: Are you checking for exactly one of `jio,zee5,voot,etc`?  Or any combination of them in any order?

Comment: No, I am checking just word containing forex: ```zee5``` to this row.

Comment: Searching for a single term, I vote for `FULLTEXT` and `WHERE MATCH(streamingtype) AGAINST('+zee5' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` as the fastest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `id` uniquely specifies the row, then you should have

```
PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

For the numeric (and date, etc) columns, simply have

```
INDEX(post_id),
INDEX(imdbRating),
INDEX(year)
```

and use things like

```
WHERE year = 1970
  AND imbdRating >= 4
```

For the `TEXT` fields, use `FULLTEXT`:

```
FULLTEXT(genres),
FULLTEXT(cast),
FULLTEXT(posterURLs)
```

and

```
WHERE MATCH(cast) AGAINST('Brando')
```

There are possibly better ways to do `genre`.  How many different values are there?  Do you need to test for one only?  Or many, such as

```
WHERE MATCH(genres) AGAINST('drama romance')
```

On a side note, what does `age` mean?  If it refers to how many years ago the movie came out, that is a bad way to store the info because *all* entries change every year.  Instead, test on `year`.

Some queries are likely to involve multiple tests.  If you have a million movies, some such queries will likely be slow.  Come back with some specific, slow, queries for further refinement -- as in "composite" indexes and/or combining columns in `FULLTEXT`.

**More**  (after query, etc, were added to the Question)

`ORDER BY  mo.year DESC, pd.date DESC` -- No index can be used for this since it involves two tables.

`WHERE ... tr.term_id IN (...)` turns the `LEFT JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`.  (This confuses the reader.)  If the "genres check" is optional, remove both the `JOIN` and the `AND .. IN`.  That is, dynamically build the query based on the arguments that the user provided.

`GROUP BY pd.id` implies that you can somehow get multiple rows from the joins.  This is the "explode-implode syndrome" that can be avoided by (and sped up by) something like

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT ...  -- as little as possible
               FROM ... JOIN ... 
               WHERE ...
               ORDER BY ...
               LIMIT ... ) AS x
    JOIN ... -- to whatever was not picked up in `x`.
```

(Sorry, but I got lost in your query, so I hesitate to spell it out completely for you.)

The `EXISTS` could be done using `INNER JOIN`.  It may not matter which way.  (Or it may work better.)

This may help:

```
pd:  INDEX(type, status)
```

If `pd.type` always tracks `mo.type`, then an extra check may be avoidable.

**More 2**

A composite index to have on `tr`: `INDEX(post_id, term_id)`.  Furthermore, if that table is simply a many-to-many mapping then toss it's `id` and have:

```
PRIMARY KEY(post_id, term_id),
INDEX(term_id, post_id)
```

More discussion:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)
It discusses how to design indexes based on queries.

**After tossing EXISTS**

```
      pd.id = mo.post_id 
      mo.type = "movie" /* checks movies / shows */ /* platforms check */
      mo.streamingInfo REGEXP "jio|zee5|voot" /* genres check */
```

needs

```
mo:  INDEX(post_id, type, streamingInfo)  -- in this order
```

And

```
    FROM  movies
    WHERE  cast REGEXP "(Cast Title)"
      AND  post_id <> 123456
      AND  post_id <> 0
    ORDER BY  year DESC
```

*may* benefit from

```
INDEX(cast)
```

or it may need

```
MATCH(cast) AGAINST("cast title")
FULLTEXT(cast)
```

**Github**

Query 1:  If none of the filters are present *and* the two types are redundant, then `INDEX(type, status) could be useful.. (Either order for the columns).

```
term_relation:  INDEX(obj_id, tax_id)  -- in this order
```

Query 2:  `INDEX(post_id)`

Query 3:  If `FULLTEXT` and `MATCH` would work that is the way to go.

Query 4:  I don't see the `JOIN` to table `sd`

Things that prevent further optimizations:

- `ORDER BY` mentioning two tables
- No obvious way to find the `LIMIT` rows *before* reaching into all the tables.
- `REGEXP`
- Filtering on inside `TEXT` or `JSON`.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147650/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-how-to-manage-mysql-database-table-index); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever GUI you are using to manage your database should have some way to add an index.

**Using sql**

To create a unique index

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```

To allow duplicates

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```

**How to decide which columns to index**

- Start by adding indexes to columns that are central in your queries and that will return large matching rows.  Possibly any column that has `id` in its name.
- Then fine tune to improve the speed of critical queries.

Comment: You mean to give index only that fields that I want to filter and get amount of records right?

Comment: It's not that simple.  Columns tested by `=` should come before the 'range' tests.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Although the post by Rick James gives a quick answer.

But, directly jumping to implementing INDEXes (especially by a novice) can be dangerous and can degrade insert-performances significantly.

> Indexes are double-ended sword, should be used with caution.

You can learn more at https://use-the-index-luke.com/